# How to create a popup window in Xcode Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, popup

I have an iOS info app. The main screen of the app consists of rows of icons. I want that after tap on certain icon card with information appears and background blurs. To close the card I need to swipe up or down. It is very similar to Instagram's imageviewer. 
Please help me create that.

P.S. This is my first project so please keep this in mind when you going to describe the method.

It should look like this

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is probably hidden beneath the layers of how you can [segue between the scenes](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/) of a storyboard. First, you create a scene like this in the storyboard and use some third party libraries to present it as a 'pop-up'. It is not possible for you to do that natively as Apple has not added any segue style showing the scene like a pop-up on the iPhone screens (On iPad it's possible - check how Apple presents choose Wi-fi network in Settings). For that purpose, you can use [BlurryModalSegue](https://github.com/Citrrus/BlurryModalSegue) or [CNPPopupController](https://github.com/carsonxyz/CNPPopupController) to perform such operations.

Thank You!